# How come azure openai models are faster than openai models?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, openai-api, gpt-4

I recently tried gpt-4 model with API calls to azure and openai. Noticed that time taken by models in azure is **at least** 2X faster.

What could be the reason behind this? Like has azure shared any details around this change in speed?